# Is there a way to make a vbs script that counts days?

Tags: javascript, powershell, vbscript

I want to make a program with vbs, when opened it has a pop up message that says  to do something. I have the program in my startup folder on my computer so it pops up every time i turn on my computer. The problem is if I miss a day then it wont say that. So i was wondering if there was a way where I could have a variable that is set so that every day it adds +1 to the variable and then in the message it says (Example, "You have not clicked OK in '2' days"). This way I can keep track of how many days I have missed and then it is a message box in vbs so there would be an 'ok' and 'cancel' option, so would it be possible to make it so when i select 'ok' then it would reset the variable to 0 again?
If this is possible could someone help me out with the code? Or if it can be done with PowerShell or javascript instead post that code instead please?
 Thank You!

P.S: Yes I have googled it and tried figuring out how to do it, for almost 2 hours. Asking on forms is ALWAYS my last resort.

Comment: Can it be done? Yes.  But StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  There are people who will help you if you get stuck at a particular spot, but "Please write this for me" questions are frowned upon.

Comment: I have asked these questions before on here and I have had nice community members write up scripts for me that I can use

Comment: I'm sure it has happened before, but it *shouldn't* and questions like that shouldn't be asked here.  I am going to assume that the reason why you've created a new account is because you've run into problems asking bad questions here before.

Comment: no, i forgot my email and password XD

Comment: Where would you recommend I go to get help with this? Any forms you can recommend? Stack Exchange has been my go to for awhile now and lately I haven't been finding much help on here...

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess I asked too much and I realize that, sorry. I can figure out the variables and im some what familiar with the rest except one part, how do I get the script to keep track of days, as in add +1 to a variable every day the 'OK' button is not pressed?